# Sharepoint 2010 - frequently freezes

Tags: sql, troubleshooting

We have serious problem with Sharepoint 2010 - system freezes for some minutes (2, 5, 10, 15..). This may occur once or twice a day, but may be 2 - 3 hours successively.

CPU usage on SQL Server drops to 0 - 3%.
After that CPU usage grows up to normal 40-60% usage and system working again.

I'm using IIS reset or SQL Server reboot to return Sharepoint to life, because during hovering all work processes are stopped. You can not start new workflow, or stop active.
As a result I have many errors with user tasks, and I have to to restart many workflows too. What could it be? I can not determine the cause of lags for a long time .. One thing is clear - the reason hides at SQL.

Comment: Sorry for my eng

Comment: What is your farm topology and is it speced for the minimum SharePoint system requirements?

Comment: Well.. we have 2 servers only. SQL server and one application server. Not rather well but..

SQL - XEON X5650 2.67, 2 processors + 32GB RAM
APP - XEON X5650 2.67, 2 processors + 32GB (+32 virtual) RAM

OS 64bit MS Server 2008 R2

Comment: 400Gb ContentDB, system tempdb DB consists of two files.

Comment: How many application pools are there on the app server and how often do they recycle?

Comment: There are 12 pools (one of them is always stopped [SharePoint Web Services Root]). I don't know anything about pools recycling. Is it important moment?

Comment: You should invest some time in more root-cause analysis. Which error message is displayed to your users? Watch your Logs (Eventviewer, ULS-Logs, SQL-Server Logs) during the outage for possible causes. Try to figure out if other Jobs are running at this time (Backup etc.). I've also seen some trouble with AntiVirus-Programs. Try to disable them to see if your problem still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some points to consider to potentially improve SQL and general performance. These are not exhaustive and are based on personal SharePoint experience.

- Consider splitting your 400GB content database into smaller databases.  Microsoft recommend that you limit your content databases to 200GB to mimimise the risk of performance issues.  Note that content databases up to 4TB are supported but generally should only be used for low I/O and collaboration cases such as archives and record centres.
- SharePoint saves all file contents in SQL Server as unstructured data, known as Binary Large Objects or BLOBs which have to be assembled every time they're requested. Large BLOBs require more processing power and time to return from SQL to the user.  Consider moving some of your largest files (such as media, CAD files for example) onto a file share or SAN and including it in your SharePoint crawl.
- Similarly to the point above, you can move old/archive data to a different database to free up space in your 'main' database for day to day work.
- Check your List View Threshold and ensure it's in line with the recommended limit (5000). Central Admin --> Application Management --> Manage Web Application --> Web Application --> General Settings --> Resource Throttling.
- Defragment database indexes and make sure your maintenance plans are keeping things tidy.  Do not run these during operational hours.
- Consider adding in an additional application server to handle search and indexing - this will greatly reduce the load on your web front end.
- Configure your crawls to run incrementally during the day and if necessary, full crawls out of hours.
- Minimise unique permissions as a large number of unique permissions can have a detrimental effect on overall performance.

See [this page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.14).aspx) for Microsoft's guidance on boundaries and limits - particularly in relation to the content database.